# Select text in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm able to focus a `react-select` programmatically, but I can't select the text in the input field.

I'm getting a reference to `react-select` like so:

```
const selectRef = useRef()
...
<Select
  ref={selectRef}
  // other props
</Select>
```

And then:

```
selectRef.current.focus()
selectRef.current.select()
```

`Select` focuses successfully, but for the second line (which I believe [should work on an `input` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)) I get:

```
TypeError: selectRef.current.select is not a function
```

How do I select text inside the `react-select`'s `input` field?

Comment: does that help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-select`, I believe, handles this focus programmatically. The `ref.current` is not the search input.

We can achieve the expected behaviour using the same [HTMLInputElement's select()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) method, however.
`react-select` provides a prop `inputId` whose value is attached directly to the input as an Id. `onFocus` we can select it.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

function SingleSelect() {
  const selectRef = useRef(null);

  function handleButtonClick() {
    selectRef.current.focus();
  }

  function handleFocus() {
    document.querySelector("#select-input").select();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Select 
        inputId = "select-input"
        ref={selectRef}
        onFocus = {handleFocus}
        options = {[
          {value: "1", label: "one"},
          {value: "2", label: "two"},
        ]}
        defaultInputValue = "some random string"
      />
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Focus!</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eqmmur) of the same code.
I hope this is what you wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of changes -:

```
<Select
  ref={(n) => this.selectRef = n}
  // other props
</Select>
```

And we can access the `inputValue` like this --> `this.selectRef.select.props.inputValue`

Working Fiddle -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-43utra

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. However, what I'm after is to make the input field active (which works) and select the text (which doesn't) so that the user can start typing a new value. For that, I need to get a `ref` to the actual `input` element in `react-select`...

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the ref to the Select component is not the same as the innerRef to the input. You would access it instead via the following object chain...

selectRef -> current (StateManager) -> select(Select Component) -> inputRef (Input Component)

```
selectRef.current.select.inputRef.select()
```